# Rotating nested SVG with a rectangular shape

Tags: svg

I am struggling a lot with trying to rotate a composite SVG. The SVG has rectangular proportions so when I rotate it around the center, parts of the SVG are rendered outside of the viewport.

My goals is to rotate the whole SVG document 90 degrees. The only way I got this working is by making the SVG width/height square and removing `preserveAspectRatio` attribute like this:

**Original**

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="300" height="443" viewBox="0 0 77 112">`

**After rotating**

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="443" height="443" viewBox="0 0 77 112" transform="rotate(90)">`

Now the rotated SVG is inside the viewbox because I made it square dimensions, but I have a blank spacing above and below.
This is obviously unwanted.
Tried to play around with the `transform-origin` and swapping `width` and `height` values around, but can't get it to work the way I want.

See this fiddle for the rotated SVG with the unwanted white spacing on top and bottom. https://jsfiddle.net/bdkst8er/